# Can't run fsck manually - "/etc/default/rcS: No such file or directory"?

Tags: ubuntu, boot, hard-disk, fsck, e2fsck

I wanted to run disk check on my Ubuntu 22.04 boot partition, so I rebooted the machine into recovery mode and tried to run fsck.
However, I got this error:

```
/lib/recovery-mode/recovery-menu: line 80: /etc/default/rcS: No such file or directory
fsck from util-linux 2.34
/dev/nvme0n1p2 is mounted.
e2fsck: Cannon continue, aborting. 

Finished, please press ENTER
```

What could be the reason?